# Rails 7 Import Maps - import folder with custom scripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

playing around with Rails 7 and import maps. Trying to import a folder with some custom JS.

```
# config/importmap.rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"

# app/javascript/application.js
import "custom"
```

Gives `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "custom"` on Chrome
and `Uncaught Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'custom' from [shim]` on Firefox

interestingly `import "custom/script"` works fine.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `import "custom/script"` also throws an error for me (Firefox).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same problem and found the following solution:

```
# app/javascript/application.js
import "custom/my_custom_code.js"
```

This means that
`pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"` is really just making each custom JS file available under the `custom` namespace. Therefore, you still need to import each file individually.

Answer (score -4):

While this might still be a valid thing to do in some use cases, I think what I was trying to do was a bit of an anti-pattern in Rails 7.

It is very easy to use Stimulus controllers instead.

[Stimulus Handbook](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/hello-stimulus) For reference

For example, to dismiss an alert when a user clicks the "x"

```
// app/javascript/alerts_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    dismiss () {
        this.element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<div data-controller="alerts">
    <h2> Alert! </h2>
    <span data-action="click->alerts#dismiss"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
</div>
```